# Destructor not called while debugging in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unmanaged

I have a C# project in which managed C++ class is used.
This managed C++ class is wrapping an unmanaged C++ code.

I have code block like this;

```
if (true)
{
                ManagedFoo foo = new ManagedFoo();                
}

//GC.Collect(); // I also tried with this one but result is same
```

I have placed a simple output string to destructor of class.

If I run program from visual studio, destructor of foo is not called.
But if I run program by double clicking on it(it is a console application),
destructor is called immediately.

Why it is behaving like this?

Many thanks,
Regards

Comment: duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755680/gc-collect-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-debug-mode
?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but aren't C++ destructors mapped to IDisposable.Dispose in C++/CLI? If so, you have to call Dispose or rather wrap it in a using block, just like with any other IDisposable:

```
using (ManagedFoo foo = new ManagedFoo()) {
    /// Use foo in here
}
```

The question linked by nob explains why the behaviour may be different between debugging and running directly. I bet the destructor is called in the finalizer, if you didn't call it explicitly.