# c# : why GC can't collect Weakreference's target in my code?

Tags: c#, weak-references

I wrote this code:

```
            dog joe = new dog();
            WeakReference wr = new WeakReference(joe);
            if (wr.IsAlive)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes,first time");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No,first time");
            }

            GC.Collect();

            if (wr.IsAlive)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes,second time");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No,second time");
            }
```

And I expected to have this result: 
Yes,first time
No,second time

but it seems that GC didn't collect my WeakReference's target(joe).
and result was:
Yes,first time
Yes,second time

What is my problem?.. do I misunderstand the WeakReferences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct. Compile as Release and run without the debugger (Shift+F5) or directly from command prompt. For an explanation see [Does garbage collection run during debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165353/does-garbage-collection-run-during-debug)

Comment: Or set joe to null when running in debug.

Comment: @IanRingrose That is the fastest method, but it wouldn't show the ability of the GC to see that a local variable isn't used anymore (and some persons say you shouldn't do it, because you are extending the lifetime of the variable)